# ¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo desde una palabra clave o línea específica que está dentro del archivo?

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo leer un archivo desde una palabra clave o línea específica que está dentro del archivo .lis o .txt o .csv hasta otra línea o palabra clave?

Quiero que sólo me tome los datos que hay entre esa línea o palabras.

Comment: Tendrás que leer todo el archivo con un bucle y usar `continue` hasta que se cumpla la condición que quieres.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias usar un bucle for de esta manera para que te lo meta durante todo el fichero, o bien cambiarlo por un while que cuando vea que final y principio son true te devuelva la lista con el contenido que necesitas. Con la funcion split puedes dividir la lista desde el punto que quieras. Tambien te recomiendo que te mires como hacerlo con expresiones regulares, que puede resultarte mas sencillo. Espero que te sirva de ayuda!!!

```
f = open("mifichero","r")

lineas = f.readlines()
principio = false
lista_lineas= []
for linea in lineas:

   if not principio:

      aux = linea.split("<palabra inical a buscar>")

      if len(aux) > 0:
        lista_lineas.append(aux[1])
        principio=true
   else:
      aux = linea.split("<palabra final a buscar>")
      if len(aux)>0:
         lista_lineas.append(aux[0])
         principio=false    
      else:
         lista_lineas.append(linea)
return lista_lineas
```